# Using dup for calculations in a Java method

Tags: java, jvm, javac

I currently have a method that does the follow: given: value, offset, stride, it adds offset to value keeping it within a group of size stride.
Examples:

> 20, 5, 30 => 25
>   29, 5, 30 => 4
>   42, 5, 30 => 47

And my current code is:

```
int cycle(int value, int offset, int stride) {
    final int rem = value % stride;
    return ((rem + offset) % stride - rem + value);
}
```

Which compiles to the following:

```
int cycle(int, int, int);
  Code:
     0: iload_1
     1: iload_3
     2: irem
     3: istore        4
     5: iload         4
     7: iload_2
     8: iadd
     9: iload_3
    10: irem
    11: iload         4
    13: isub
    14: iload_1
    15: iadd
    16: ireturn
```

Is there any combination of code changes and / or compiler options that can make it produce something like this instead? (The example was written by hand):

```
int cycle(int, int, int);
  Code:
     0: iload_1
     1: iload_3
     2: irem
     3: dup
     4: iload_2
     5: iadd
     6: iload_3
     7: irem
     8: isub
     9: iload_1
    10: iadd
    11: ireturn
```

Comment: Are you hoping the latter bytecode would be generated because it would perform better?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no such javac option. But why do you need this?

Comment: Essentially, yes. I realize there's still a translation to native machine code which might further optimize things.  The alternative I considered was inlining rem.  Upon benchmarking this though, it seems like it doesn't really matter in the end, with a test loop of 1 billion calls, both ways produces timings of roughly 0.25ns per call.

Comment: The second way was replacing rem with value % stride in the source.  The timings I got however were inaccurate, though fixing it still produced consistent results. It turns out The JVM detected it was called with all constant input, and optimized out the method entirely.

Comment: that is why 1) listen and accept Holger's answer as he is absolutely correct 2) look into `jmh` if you want to micro-benchmark a java method

Answer (score 1):

Most optimizing JVMs, most notably the commonly using HotSpot JVM, will transform the code into the [SSA form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) before applying any other optimization. For this representation, it is entirely irrelevant whether the original code used temporary local variables or `dup` on the operand stack, the in­ter­me­di­ate representation will be the same.

So `javac` doesn’t offer any option to control the byte code representation of such a construct, but it doesn’t matter anyway.

Comment: It turns out that when it's JIT'd, the variable never gets written to the stack at all. Since it stays in a register, it's just reused where it's needed. (If that's what the SSA form is, I apologize, I only have understood that article)

Comment: @Tahg the SSA form is an *intermediate* representation that doesn’t even have a notion of a stack. It’s basically a kind of graph connecting actual use of variables (their actual values) with their source. This effectively eliminates all intermediate transfers between variables and operand stack and between different variables. That’s what my answer says, “*it is entirely irrelevant whether the original code used temporary local variables or dup on the operand stack, the in­ter­me­di­ate representation will be the same*”. From that SSA representation, it finally gets assigned to a CPU register